Unable to call the remote GetWindows gnome method via dbus
I'm trying to call the GetWindows method from the gnome dbus api https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/blob/main/data/dbus-interfaces/org.gnome.Shell.Introspect.xml
When I run the code below I get the error GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed (g-dbus-error-quark, 9)
AccessDenied led me to think that I needed to run the code via sudo, but this gave another error: The name org.gnome.Shell was not provided by any .service files
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glib/gprintf.h>
#include <gio/gio.h>


void test_getwindows(GDBusProxy *proxy)
{
   GError *error = NULL;
   g_printf("Calling GetWindows()...\n");
   g_dbus_proxy_call_sync(proxy,
           "GetWindows",
           NULL,
           G_DBUS_CALL_FLAGS_NONE,
           -1,
           NULL,
           &error);
   g_assert_no_error(error);
}

int main(void)
{
   GDBusProxy *proxy;
   GDBusConnection *conn;
   GError *error = NULL;

   conn = g_bus_get_sync(G_BUS_TYPE_SESSION, NULL, &error);
   g_assert_no_error(error);

   proxy = g_dbus_proxy_new_sync(conn,
              G_DBUS_PROXY_FLAGS_NONE,
              NULL,
              "org.gnome.Shell", 
              "/org/gnome/Shell/Introspect",
              "org.gnome.Shell.Introspect",
              NULL,
              &error);
   g_assert_no_error(error);

   test_getwindows(proxy);
   return 0;
}       

Full errors:
without sudo: ERROR:dbus-getwindows.c:18:test_getwindows: assertion failed (error == NULL): GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed (g-dbus-error-quark, 9) Bail out! ERROR:dbus-getwindows.c:18:test_getwindows: assertion failed (error == NULL): GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: App introspection not allowed (g-dbus-error-quark, 9) Aborted (core dumped)
with sudo: ERROR:dbus-getwindows.c:18:test_getwindows: assertion failed (error == NULL): GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.Shell was not provided by any .service files (g-dbus-error-quark, 2) Bail out! ERROR:dbus-getwindows.c:18:test_getwindows: assertion failed (error == NULL): GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.Shell was not provided by any .service files (g-dbus-error-quark, 2) Aborted
Ubuntu 20, wayland

There is no version of Ubuntu simply called 20. Please edit the question and put in the actual version info. As for the error you are getting seems it is a question for whom ever made the script from git hub your are using.
